# Why does all members of a class show error 'CS0103'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, memory, visual-studio-debugging

I'm testing a piece of code in c# and vs2022, but I encounter some problems. I try to track the value of some members in a class, but the VS2022 shows error CS0103.
So I would like to know why VS2022 can't show their values because they are certainly in this context.

```cs
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProtoType p = new ProtoType(100, 200);

        p.x = 101;
        p.y = 20;
        int cnt = p.list.Count;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class ProtoType
{
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    public List<string> list = new List<string>();

    public ProtoType(int x, int y)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Execute Constructor ProtoType()");
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public ProtoType Clone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Execute ProtoType.Clone()");
        return (ProtoType)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's worth making it very, very clear that this is not a *compile-time* error, but an error when debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `x`, `y` and `list` are not variables in this scope. they are members of the class `ProtoType`. you need to watch for `p.x`, `p.y` and `p.list` in place of the x, `y`, `list`.

Comment: Or just watch `p` and drill down in the GUI